# RoR: Parsing html &lt; into < and other similar HTML to literals

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, rubygems

I'm using the GCal4Ruby gems plugin.

I'm trying to get it render an embedded google calendar.

So the relevant method is to_iframe as described here:

http://cookingandcoding.com/docs/gcal4ruby/classes/GCal4Ruby/Service.html

When I call the method, it produces:

Figure 1

```
<iframe src ="relevant_and_working_Gcal_URL" width="100%" height="300">
  text here
</iframe>"
```

displayed as text in the page, which is sort of what I want but looking at the source it renders as:

Figure 2:

```
&lt;iframe src ="relevant_and_working_Gcal_URL" width="100%" height="300"&gt;
  text here
&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

So my question is there any ruby method that will take in a string argument and do the relevant replacements?

In other words, it would take in the string figure 2 and return the string in figure 1.

I'll post an exact example when I can get back in an hour or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3 use the raw method to output the raw html.

```
<%= raw @service.to_iframe %>
```